# Create a dynamic array of pointer over 2D Array

Tags: c

I'm kind of stuck since i'm trying to do what is in the title.
instinctively i would do this :

```
size = 10 //(for example)
int** pieces[10][10];
pieces* = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*size);
```

But it doesn't even compile.

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you !

Comment: "it doesn't even compile" why not? what is the exact error? anyway, this is surely answered 100s of times already.

Comment: `int** pieces[10][10];` You probably either want `int pieces[10][10];` or `int** pieces;`

Comment: What do you want to make? One 10×10 array of `int`? An n×n array of `int`, where `n` is not known at compile time? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In order not to mix up the syntax with "array of pointers", you need to do this:

```
int (*pieces) [10][10]; // pointer to int [10][10]
```

And then to allow convenient access with syntax `pieces[i][j]` rather than `(*pieces)[i][j]`, drop the outer-most dimension:

```
int (*pieces) [10]; // pointer to int[10], the type of the first element of a int[10][10].
```

Allocate with

```
pieces = malloc( sizeof(int[10][10]) );
...
free(pieces);
```

Details here: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to make a pointer to a pointer to an array of 2d of ints.
you need to delete the bracktes ([10][10])
you should allocate an array of pointers for the rows `pieces = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*size);`
and then allocate for each column with a loop like this:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    pieces[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

afterwards you will need to free all the column allocations and then first row allocation of pieces.

Comment: Please do not recommend people make arrays like this. It has become popular in amateur circles, but it is bad for performance (due to requiring multiple pointer loads and other effects) and is a nuisance to manage. In many C implementations, an m×n array of `int` can be allocated simply with `int (*a)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof *a);`. In implementations without support for variable length arrays, space can be allocated using `int *a = malloc(m * n * sizeof *a);` and then used with manual subscript calculations.